# Boost error in has_new_operator.hpp when debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, boost, boost-geometry

I'm using VC-Express 2013. I have integrated a header from a different project that utilized the boost library and when compiling in releasemode everything is fine. When I'm trying to compile in debug-mode I'm getting several of the following errors:

```
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : ']'  
has_new_operator.hpp    67  1   
Error   3   error C2976: 'boost::detail::test' : too few template arguments 
has_new_operator.hpp    68  1   
Warning 7   warning C4346: 'U::new' : dependent name is not a type  
has_new_operator.hpp    89  1
```

The begin of the included headerfile looks like this:

```
#ifndef AREACLASS_H_
#define AREACLASS_H_

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "global.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/wkt/wkt.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include "triangulation.h"
#include "SplineContainerClass.h"

class AreaClass
{
private:
    rectangle<double> boundingbox;
    SplineContainerClass *SplineContainer;
    polygon boundary_polygon;
    Vector2dVector polygonTriangles;

public:
    AreaClass();
    AreaClass(SplineContainerClass *_SplineContainer);
    AreaClass(GenericSplineClass *_Spline);
    ~AreaClass();
    void appendSpline(GenericSplineClass *_Spline);
    void appendSpline(SplineContainerClass *_SplineContainer);
    void appendSplineReverse(SplineContainerClass *_SplineContainer);
    bool DeleteSplineContainer();
    bool GeneratePolygon();
    void DrawPrototypView(bool Highlight, bool DrawTangents);


    //Accessor Functions
    double minx() { return(boundingbox.left); }
    double maxx() { return(boundingbox.right); }
    double miny() { return(boundingbox.bottom); }
    double maxy() { return(boundingbox.top); }
};

#endif /* AREACLASS_H_ */
```

Even when I make AreaClass an empty Class and remove triangulation.h and SplineContainerClass.h the same errors show up.  What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your code above appears to be trimmed, please provide the full code.

Comment: Here is the full areaclass.h. As I said, the same errors appear even when the AreaClass is just a stub.

Comment: Then it isn't related to the AreaClass. I'll post an answer soon which could show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does stdafx.h contain any `#define new DEBUG_NEW` stuff? If so, then just comment out that line and the build will likely pass.